# Is it safe to store password in EncryptedSharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is it safe to store passwords in EncryptedSharedPreferences?

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences

Comment: The general recommendation is **not to store** any passwords, better use something like Argon2i or Bcrypt or Scrypt.